# prove strictly convexity

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis, positive-definite

I wanna show $f(x)=-x^{\top}p+c\cdot\sqrt{x^\top\Sigma x}$ is strictly convex, where $p$ is a constant vector, $\Sigma$ is positive definite. I tried to show it by using $f''(x)$ is positive definite and I could obtain

$$H(x)=c\cdot \frac{\Sigma -\frac{(\Sigma x)(\Sigma x)^{\top}}{x^\top\Sigma x}}{\sqrt{x^\top \Sigma x}}$$

yet I am stuck here. Could someone help me clarify it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not differentiable in $x = 0$, so you can't prove strict convexity by using the second derivative.

Also, the function is not strictly convex. Note that $f$ is positively homogenous of degree $1$, which implies that for any $x \ne 0$ the following holds: 
$$f\big(\tfrac{1}{2} x + \tfrac{1}{2}2x\big) = f\big(\tfrac{3}{2} x) = \frac{3}{2} f(x) = \frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{2} 2f(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2} f(2x).$$

However, the function is indeed convex for $c \ge 0$. We can ignore the part $-x^tp$, since this is a linear function; The only difficult part is proving that $x \mapsto \sqrt{x^t \Sigma x}$ is convex. To this extent, note that for any $x, y$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ the following holds by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, applied to the inner product $\langle x, y \rangle = x^t \Sigma y$:

$$(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)^t\Sigma (\lambda x + (1 - \lambda y) = \lambda^2 x^t \Sigma x + 2(1 - \lambda) \lambda x^t \Sigma y + (1 - \lambda)^2 y^t \Sigma y\\
\le \lambda^2 x^t \Sigma x + 2 (1 - \lambda) \lambda \sqrt{x^t \Sigma x} \sqrt{y^t \Sigma y} + (1 - \lambda)^2 y^t \Sigma y = \big(\lambda \sqrt{x^t\Sigma x} + (1 - \lambda) \sqrt{y^t \Sigma y}\big)^2$$

Note that in the first equality we have used that $\Sigma$ is wlog symmetric, which implies 
$$y^t\Sigma x = (y^t \Sigma x)^t = x^t \Sigma^t y = x^t \Sigma y.$$

Comment: Hi @Dominik Thanks a lot!!! Forgot to mention that $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $\sum_{1}^{n}x_{i]$ and $x_{i} \geq 0$. Yes, it is convex as you mentioned yet I am sorry that the argument of positively homogeneity does not convince me it is not strictly convex since f(\lambda x) when \lambda \neq 1 does not match the assumption.

Comment: one more correction.. $\sum_{1}^{n} x_{i}=1$

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your formula. I guess you want to consider this function on the standard simplex? Then it is strictly convex. Note that equality holds in my calculations if and only if $\lambda \in \{0, 1\}$ or we have equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But this only happens if $y = 0$ or $x = \alpha y$ for some nonnegative parameter $\alpha$.